# calling one js function from other js file?

Tags: javascript

I have two .js files(A,B). i want to call functions of B.js into A.js file. How can i'll be done.

**A.js:**

```
function validation(){
  alert("validating...");
}
```

**B.js:**

```
function login(){
  // i want to call validation() of file A.js here. How can it possible
  validation();

}
```

Comment: Include both the files in you html. Then you should be able to call the function

Comment: What's the problem? Assuming this is in a browser context, there is no implicit scope for each js file. If you declare functions like in your example, they both end up in the global scope when the browser builds the document and there should be no problem calling one function from the other.

Answer (score 3):

include the a.js file to b.js

```
function includeJs(ajsfilepath) {
    var js = document.createElement("script");

    js.type = "text/javascript";
    js.src = jsFilePath;

    document.body.appendChild(js);
}

includeJs("/path/a.js");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use scripting to dynamically include the javascript files, you can add the following lines in your html file:

```
<script src="A.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="B.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Then, it should work.

Comment: You didn't get my point. I don't want to use in html file. I want to use A.js's method into b.js file. Anyway I got answer. Thanks :)